# mysql, use two select and order by, new value

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.ad, c.name, c.phone, c.email,
    (
        SELECT b.id_user
        FROM price_b b
        WHERE b.id = a.id
        ORDER BY b.date DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS f_user_id
    FROM a_emtp a
    LEFT JOIN customer c ON
    c.id = f_user_id
    WHERE a.show = "1"
```

Hi, why show this error: Unknown column 'f_user_id' in 'on clause'

Thanks

Comment: what are you attempting to do btw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.ad, c.name, c.phone, c.email,
(
    SELECT b.id_user
    as f_user_id
    FROM price_b b
    WHERE b.id = a.id
    ORDER BY b.date DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
FROM a_emtp a
LEFT JOIN customer c ON
c.id = f_user_id
WHERE a.show = "1"
```

You can reference labelled fields from subqueries inside outer queries. You could even drop the relabelling and just use "b.id_user".

Answer (score 0):

Probably a comma after c.email was missing.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.ad, c.name, c.phone, c.email,
(
    SELECT b.id_user
    FROM price_b b
    WHERE b.id = a.id
    ORDER BY b.date DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS f_user_id
FROM a_emtp a
LEFT JOIN customer c ON
c.id = f_user_id
WHERE a.show = "1"
```